# Garbage Collection in-case of Child / Forked Processes in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, process, garbage-collection

I was ready an article on **Ruby's GC (Garbage Collection)** today and I got confused over few points.

Let's say we are using **Unicorn** to serve our site. Unicorn uses worker processes to handle requests. Worker processes normally are forked processes of parent / master process. Now my question is that where does GC happen? I mean do each forked process have it's own copy of Ruby process running and GC happens for each forked process separately or do each forked process use same Ruby process i.e. from master process and GC happens there? If latter is true then how does forked process share things such as Ruby from parent process.

To my understanding each forked process have it's own version of Ruby running which gets copied when child process was forked.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It used to be true that each forked process got its own copy of the entire memory space of the parent process. This is why process based web servers for Ruby tended to need so much memory until recently.

As of Ruby 2.0 however, forked processes now adhere to the Copy on Write principle. That is to say, a forked process shares as much data with its parent process as possible. This means that child processes use a lot less memory than they used to as they no longer need to copy the entire memory space of their parent process. When a child process needs to modify a part of the memory it shares with its parent process (or the parent process needs to modify a part of the memory it shares with a child), the child process will make a copy of just that part. That's why it's called Copy on Write :)

Regarding Garbage Collection, that happens in each Ruby process. The above explanation should hopefully make it clear why such an approach works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and for explaining this in a clear way. You are right regarding COW principle and I know about that but you really explained it concisely. So each child process will have it's own Ruby process running and Garbage Collection happens for each process separately. This means that in worker processes model even MRI can benefit from parallel execution if system has more cores because each process is running and handled independently. Am I right?

Comment: you are correct. Process parallelization is done by the OS and as such  does not suffer from the same drawbacks as Ruby threads do (threads running in the same process will not execute in parallel due to the GIL).